# MacOS High Sierra crashes after a while

Tags: macos, crash, high-sierra, kernel-panic

Every time I start my MacBook, everything works fine.

For around 3 minutes. Afterwards, it crashes with a kernel panic. I am forced to write this question in safe mode, as booting normally will make it crash again.

Images:

[image: Kernel panic]

[image: Crash log]

[image: More crash log]

Complete crash logs (different from the screenshot):

```
Anonymous UUID:       E7E6C136-6CDE-3815-83B4-98D2458B7659

Tue Dec 12 17:56:00 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8010a6627c): "IOVideoPocketCamDevice[0x100000498]::terminate(kIOServiceSynchronous) timeout\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.31.3/iokit/Kernel/IOService.cpp:2289
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92374b3830 : 0xffffff80104505f6 
0xffffff92374b3880 : 0xffffff801057d604 
0xffffff92374b38c0 : 0xffffff801056f0f9 
0xffffff92374b3940 : 0xffffff8010402120 
0xffffff92374b3960 : 0xffffff801045002c 
0xffffff92374b3a90 : 0xffffff801044fdac 
0xffffff92374b3af0 : 0xffffff8010a6627c 
0xffffff92374b3b40 : 0xffffff8010a69d27 
0xffffff92374b3bc0 : 0xffffff8010a89561 
0xffffff92374b3bf0 : 0xffffff8010a89755 
0xffffff92374b3c30 : 0xffffff8010a1ec51 
0xffffff92374b3c70 : 0xffffff8010a24f25 
0xffffff92374b3cf0 : 0xffffff8010a33c5e 
0xffffff92374b3d60 : 0xffffff80104a59b7 
0xffffff92374b3dc0 : 0xffffff8010455c30 
0xffffff92374b3e10 : 0xffffff8010432cbd 
0xffffff92374b3e60 : 0xffffff8010445b7b 
0xffffff92374b3ef0 : 0xffffff801055952d 
0xffffff92374b3fa0 : 0xffffff8010402926 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kextunload
Boot args: -r -s

Mac OS version:
17C88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 87641697-A3DD-30C4-B010-E65ECE57550B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000010000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8010200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8010100000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 175347811394
last loaded kext at 71034379550: com.avast.FileShield   4.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f97750000, size 577536)
loaded kexts:
com.avast.FileShield    4.0.0
com.avast.PacketForwarder   2.1
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.1.1
com.techsmith.TACC  1.0.3
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner.VirtualHIDDevice.v040800  4.8.0
com.senstic.driver.PocketCamDevice  1.0.0
com.paragon-software.kext.VDMounter 111.2
com.protech.NoSleep 1.4.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.5
com.senstic.driver.PocketAudioDevice    1.2
com.cyberic.SmoothMouse 9
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4718
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.16.21
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.13
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.24
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   280.12
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC-MFG    1220.28.1a3
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.10.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.16.21
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1220.28.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  404.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 127
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  127
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.31.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.30.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOVideoFamily   1.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStreamFamily  1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    650.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.2
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.22
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.21
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 1.6.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    376.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.22
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 127
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1201.8
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.6.3
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro11,5, BootROM MBP114.0177.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.30f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M370X, AMD Radeon R9 M370X, PCIe, 2 GB
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.5.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.2f2, 3 services, 27 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Non-Apple kexts that are loaded:

```
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID 
   60    0 0xffffff7f80e46000 0x4b000    0x4b000    at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch (4718) 715E9654-C3FB-39A4-9514-C770F749EE8E 
  129    0 0xffffff7f83155000 0x5000     0x5000     com.cyberic.SmoothMouse (9) C35F0329-A3A9-3153-ADBE-59909AFFBB42 
  162    0 0xffffff7f866a9000 0x4000     0x4000     com.senstic.driver.PocketAudioDevice (1.2) 49E4E01A-1C19-35CB-8346-0A080CC6EC16 
  163    0 0xffffff7f866ad000 0x5000     0x5000     com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower (1.6.5) 6B340F4E-FDD8-3A78-93A8-22361ECA1695 
  164    0 0xffffff7f866b2000 0x4000     0x4000     com.protech.NoSleep (1.4.0) 79207772-D7BF-34EE-B7B6-6E90A96D8062 
  166    0 0xffffff7f866da000 0x61000    0x61000    com.paragon-software.kext.VDMounter (111.2) 6756C3B0-A370-3698-951F-4AA79285388C 
  169    0 0xffffff7f86750000 0x6fc000   0x6fc000   com.senstic.driver.PocketCamDevice (1.0.0) 7961BB1A-D822-3560-884D-AFB3CDA9DCF4 
  170    0 0xffffff7f86e4c000 0x7000     0x7000     org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner.VirtualHIDDevice.v040800 (4.8.0) E93C6B3D-9BBE-3579-97E1-4B6F51B8A527 
  171    0 0xffffff7f86e53000 0x5000     0x5000     com.techsmith.TACC (1.0.3) 851BEDD1-1D12-3756-A948-978610078DEF 
  176    0 0xffffff7f86e7d000 0x16000    0x16000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (6.1.1) 86D6923C-EFE8-32E3-89BE-95C6A5EC5611 
  177    0 0xffffff7f86e93000 0x3000     0x3000     com.avast.PacketForwarder (2.1) EAFA1039-3CE9-34FF-9A87-B1454A03229E 
  179    0 0xffffff7f87750000 0x88000    0x88000    com.avast.FileShield (4.0.0) 69BE68AD-3AF4-31FF-8BCA-3356783C73FB
```

I know it's not Avast. The last loaded kext has nothing to do with this, I've disabled a few of the "last loaded kext"s and they didn't seem to do anything.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're on the right track with how you've started troubleshooting. Without knowing exactly what you've already tried, and for the benefit of others, I've outlined how I would normally proceed (keeping in mind that troubleshooting is a process of elimination and does require patience!).

Since you've already established the problem **is not** occurring when booted into Safe Mode then it's time to investigate login items, fonts, and kernel extensions.

**Investigating login items, fonts, and kernel extensions**

Let's start with Login Items:

1. Startup normally
2. Go to System Preferences > Users & Groups
3. Select the Login Items tab
4. Take a note of your Login Items
5. Now remove all of them by highlighting them and clicking on the <kbd>-</kbd> button below
6. Restart your computer

Now your Mac will boot up without those login items loading. Test to see if you can use your Mac without it crashing:

- If you can, you know one (or more) of the Login items were causing the problem. You can then add them back in one by one until you've identified the culprit. Problem solved.
- If the problem does persist, it's either a problem with fonts you've installed yourself or with a 3rd party kernel extension. A little more info below:

**Fonts:-** You can remove any of the fonts you've installed yourself to see if this makes a difference.

**Kernel Extensions:-** You can open Terminal (found within your Utilites folder) and enter the following command:

`kextstat | grep -v com.apple`

The above command will list 3rd party kernel extensions (you may need to stretch the Terminal window so it's easier to read). Look for anything you don't remember installing, or something that belongs to software you've removed, or just anything that looks out of place. Remember though, this is a list of **3rd party kernel extensions** and therefore any of them could be causing the problem.

If your Mac continues to crash once you've gone through the above process, I would suggest that continuing to troubleshoot this will cause more frustration and take more time than just cutting your losses and doing a fresh installation of macOS.

Comment: My guess is the cause has been there in the crash report the whole time. `IOVideoPocketCamDevice[0x100000498]::terminate(kIOServiceSynchronous)`. IOVideoPocketCamDevice was a .kext in my /Library/Extensions folder. I disabled that and /System/Library/Extensions/PocketAudioDevice.kext (both Senstic drivers). Doesn't seem like macOS has crashed yet.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson Sometimes that is the easier way to go, assuming the user has a current reliable backup. It'd almost certainly resolve the problem, so long as it's not reintroduced because of some buggy 3rd party software. But first spending a couple of hours to do some basic troubleshooting is worth it in most cases. :)

Comment: @Dev That wouldn't surprise me. The Senstic and Techsmith ones stood out a little in that list of 3rd party kexts. I did try to load the Senstic forums earlier to see if anyone else had reported issues with macOS High Sierra, but I couldn't get their forums page to load. Hopefully that will have sorted the problem for you, though.