# macOS Catalina crashing everytime

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, catalina, kernel-panic, shutdown

I have a 15" mid-2015 Retina MacBook Pro with 16 GB RAM.

After doing a clean install for macOS Catalina, my RMBP always freezes and after a couple of seconds, it shows kernel panic message and restarts. Here's the report after restarting

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8013062e0a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9649c34e, type 6=invalid opcode, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007ffeeea93d98, CR3: 0x00000000182c6000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff922616bba0
RSP: 0xffffff922616bd10, RBP: 0xffffff922616bd10, RSI: 0x0000000000000503, RDI: 0xffffff8037978600
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x0000000000989680, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000002
R12: 0x0000000000000004, R13: 0xffffff80388cfaf0, R14: 0xffffff922616bd30, R15: 0xffffff80388cfaf0
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7f9649c34e, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00007ffeeea93d98, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff922616b770 : 0xffffff8012f39a3b 
0xffffff922616b7c0 : 0xffffff8013070fe5 
0xffffff922616b800 : 0xffffff8013062a5e 
0xffffff922616b850 : 0xffffff8012ee0a40 
0xffffff922616b870 : 0xffffff8012f39127 
0xffffff922616b970 : 0xffffff8012f3950b 
0xffffff922616b9c0 : 0xffffff80136d17f9 
0xffffff922616ba30 : 0xffffff8013062e0a 
0xffffff922616bbb0 : 0xffffff8013062b08 
0xffffff922616bc00 : 0xffffff8012ee0a40 
0xffffff922616bc20 : 0xffffff7f9649c34e 
0xffffff922616bd10 : 0xffffff7f963fc490 
0xffffff922616bd50 : 0xffffff7f9640a655 
0xffffff922616bda0 : 0xffffff7f963936db 
0xffffff922616be10 : 0xffffff7f943a1966 
0xffffff922616be60 : 0xffffff7f943af438 
0xffffff922616bea0 : 0xffffff7f943aebf8 
0xffffff922616bee0 : 0xffffff80136401bd 
0xffffff922616bf30 : 0xffffff801363eb02 
0xffffff922616bf70 : 0xffffff801363e08c 
0xffffff922616bfa0 : 0xffffff8012ee013e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.2.7)[72B8A0B5-E12C-3764-9187-0AC0E93416F9]@0xffffff7f9439d000->0xffffff7f94460fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[180FC5AB-0E47-35BC-91DF-609EBE8ED4A5]@0xffffff7f93fd5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f9392f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.6)[39DC4195-B168-3895-ACD5-E731581855F8]@0xffffff7f9430d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(568)[247C211E-C250-351C-BCE2-4DB9D3003E10]@0xffffff7f9433e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[2CCA7DD3-C33F-3CA4-A213-BC83D3D997B0]@0xffffff7f93d0c000
         com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000(3.0.2)[1E092428-A3E6-3063-B692-B943B1565B91]@0xffffff7f9638a000->0xffffff7f967cffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f9392f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.6)[39DC4195-B168-3895-ACD5-E731581855F8]@0xffffff7f9430d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(568)[247C211E-C250-351C-BCE2-4DB9D3003E10]@0xffffff7f9433e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.2.7)[72B8A0B5-E12C-3764-9187-0AC0E93416F9]@0xffffff7f9439d000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19B88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7503CD47-851F-321E-8747-50DB4299165F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012d00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 297932304261
last loaded kext at 247929184800: @filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f978f6000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 219384189476: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f948e0000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   71.5.15
@filesystems.msdosfs    1.10
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.2.5
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHDA  283.14
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.2
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.2
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.9
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.9
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 14.0.2
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.1f1
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    14.0.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.5.9
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!AMuxControl   4.5.9
>eficheck   1
@kext.AMD7000!C 3.0.2
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    7.0.1f1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3410.1
>!UTopCaseDriver    3410.1
>!UCardReader   489.41.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.41.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.14
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.2
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.7
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.9
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  568
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.9
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.2
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.9
>!AHDA!C    283.14
|IOHDA!F    283.14
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   568
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.1f1
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.1f1
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.1f1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!AHS!BDriver   3410.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.1f1
|IO!B!F 7.0.1f1
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.1f1
>!AActuatorDriver   3410.2
>!AMultitouchDriver 3410.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3410.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.40.3
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.0
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.6
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.41.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Additional information: This happens when I'm using Microsoft Word and no USB devices were connected. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Most of the times, kernel panics have to be debugged by the machine owners themselves.  Read the answers on [What is a Kernel Panic and what does it mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean) and [Understanding kernel panic error log](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80000/understanding-kernel-panic-error-log) and  [How can I troubleshoot Kernel Panics on my iMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14869/) and [MacOS High Sierra crashes after a while](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308840/)

Comment: Does this crash happen when you are using [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)?

Comment: I've the same Problem, also crashing with
...
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000(3.0.2)[1E092428-A3E6-3063-B692-B943B1565B91]@0xffffff7f9796a000->0xffffff7f97daffff
...
after some time (10-30min). I have also 15" mid-2015 Retina MacBook Pro with 16 GB RAM, AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2 GB Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB